# React App compiles slowly with 50k images in public/images folder

Tags: reactjs, performance

I have a React app that requires about 50,000 product images be present in a public/images path.  When these images are present, the compile time is between 3-5 minutes -- for every code change.  When I remove the folder, the app compiles almost instantly.  Is this expected, and how can I speed things up?

Comment: Serve the images from outside the app.

Comment: It is not a best practice to merge something that can be considered as a resource (I mean data by itself) with the code. Probably this "issue" is related to how `webpack` looks to FS changes.